# Can non-polynomial expressions be represented as multivariate polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For a given expression that is not a univariate polynomial, say:

$x^3 + x^2 + x^\frac{1}{2}$

Is it permissible to do the following:

$a = x^\frac{1}{2}$

$x^3 + x^2 + x^\frac{1}{2} = x^3 + x^2 + a$

Thus concluding that $x^3 + x^2 + a$ is a bivariate polynomial?

After a bit of reading online I seem to get the idea that multivariate polynomials are polynomials in several indeterminates, yet I am unaware as to whether $a$ can be said to be just another indeterminate, making the expression a bivariate polynomial.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction concerning what is and isn't allowed? I don't understand what is meant by an indeterminate.

Comment: It's not a matter of what is "permissible" or not. Of course you can make such a definition but the question is whether you can use it for anything.

Comment: Yes, but you have actually lost information in your equation.  In the original equation, if you have a value for the expression, you can figure out what $x$ is.  You can't do that in the new expression.  There is nothing wrong with something being a non-polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the $a=x^{\frac12}$ substitution does not make the expression a multivariate polynomial. Let $$f: \mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \; f((x, a)) =x^4+x^2+a$$ be a multivariate function and suppose by way of contradiction that $a=x^{\frac12} $. Then $$f((0,1))=x^4+x^2+a=0^4+0^2+1=1$$ but also $$f((0,1))=x^4+x^2+a=0^4+0^2+x^{\frac12} =0^{\frac12} =0$$ so $0=1$ which is absurd.

However, you can use the substitution to make the expression look like a univariate polynomial. Notice that if $a=x^{\frac12}$ then $$x^2 = x^{4\cdot \frac12}=(x^{\frac12})^4=a^4$$ and similarly $$x^4=(x^2)^2=(a^4)^2=a^8$$ So the polynomial becomes $a^8+a^4+a$, which is only in function of $a$, but $a$ is in function of $x$, so the whole thing is still in function of $x$, just with a different face.

Now, a bit about variables and indeterminates. In $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \;f(a) = a+1$, $a$ is a variable: it can take any value from the domain $\mathbb{R} $, and for each value we have a corresponding value in the image. Now, in the equation $a^2+a=0$, $a$ is an indeterminate, and it has set values: it has to be either $0$ or $-1$. If it takes any value other than those, the equality is false. For example, for $a=1$, $a^2+a=0 \implies 1+1=0$ which is clearly false.

Comment: Thank you! However just to be clear, the expression $a^8 + a^4 + a$ would still not be a univariate polynomial or? Or would it still be okay to apply common polynomial factoring identities on it for example?

Comment: It would not be a univariate polynomial, but you can treat it as such and then use your solution for the polynomial with $a$ on the substitution to get the solution for the expression with $x$. For example, take $2x-x^{\frac12}=0$. Then for $a=x^{\frac12}$, we have $2a^2 - a=0$, so $a=0$ or $a=\pm \frac{1}{2}$. For the second equality, we have $\pm \frac{1}{2} = x^{\frac12} \implies x=\frac14$, which you can check is true.